# HTML Canvas measureText is way off

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw a line under a string of characters on an HTML Canvas and the value coming back from measureText is wrong.

Here's the code:

```js
var theCanvas =  document.querySelector('canvas')
var ctx = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
if (ctx) {
    var theString = "Drawing Text on a Canvas";
    ctx.font = "28px Verdana"
    ctx.fillText(theString, 20, 160);
    var textW = ctx.measureText(theString);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.moveTo(20, 170);
    ctx.lineTo(Math.round(textW.width), 170);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas width="600" height="200"></canvas>
```

The line doesn't reach all the way to the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the endpoint of the line, you're forgetting to take the offset into account. Your text starts at x = 20, then it should end at the calculated endpoint + 20

Instead of `(x,y) = Math.round(textW.width), 170`, then it should be `(x,y) = Math.round(textW.width) + 20, 170`

Comment: Well that's embarrasing. Thanks!